# fswatch not running script, reports as not found

Tags: xargs, fswatch

I have a script in ~/bin called `go_refresh`. It's definitely there. I run fswatch like so:

`fswatch -o /usr/local/var/www/wp_sites/test/wp-content/themes/test/style.css | xargs -n1 -I{} ~/bin/go_refresh`

When I change the file, I get this error once:

`xargs: /Users/my_dir/bin/go_refresh: No such file or directory`

And the script doesn't run.

Comment: I think it has something to do with the fact that `go_refresh` is a perl script. shebang line is: `#! usr/bin/env perl`

Comment: I worked around it by using a shell script instead called refresh.sh. But I would like to know why my perl script says "no such file". Weird.

Comment: Try: `#!/usr/bin/env perl` (ie. add a leading slash to path)

Comment: Doh! missed that.